# Rspec Selenium passing variable using through command and use that variable in test case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec

I have a test case like this.

```
  describe "City Sports" do
context 'xyz cases' do
  it 'checks the xyz signin' do
    visit "https://secure-xyz/"
    fill_in 'emailAddress', with: email
    fill_in 'password', with: "password1"
    find_button('signInButton').trigger('click')
    if current_url == "https://secure-xyz.do"
      #click_button 'Register'
      fill_in 'newEmailAddress', with: email
      find_button('registerButton').trigger('click')
      fill_in 'password', with: 'password1'
      find_button('registrationSubmitButton').trigger('click')
    end
  end
end
```

I have this test case and the variable email which I am being use in the test case I want to pass through command line like 
rspec spec/users:#{email}/sign_in.rb

how can In pass email variable through command line and how can I get this variable in test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding the all of the test cases in rake task and I am calling it via.

```
email="abcAgmail.com,password" rake task:task
```

and its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet (if you really want to go down this route) will be to look into using a rake file because as far as I know, without customising the rspec command (I wouldn't recommend this) you won't be able to pass in a variable.

The other cleaner solution will be to keep things like test email addresses inside some sort of config which can then be consumed by your test. For example you could have a test data module:

```
module TestData
  module Users
    def known_user
      { email: 'email@example.com', password: 'password' }
    end
  end
end
```

This can then be accessed in your test with `TestData::Users.known_user` and appending `[:email]` or `[:password]` depending on which bit of data you're trying to get at. The benefit of this is you're not having to pass variables into tests. After all, surely you're going to want to eventually run a whole test suite and having to provide arguments for each test will become a nightmare.